# HAL browser is not showing URL in the list

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a spring-data-rest project with hal browser. The method I have is returning `List<String>` but it is not listed in the hal browser list of url. However I can access it. My method is

```
@RestController
public class UtilRepository {
    private SomeClass someClass ;
    @GetMapping("/getSomething")
    List<String> getSomethingUsingRest(){
        someClass = new SomeClass();
        try {
           return Arrays.asList(someClass.getArrayOfRecords());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can access `http://localhost:8080/getSomething` but when running the program using hal browser, the url `/getSomething` is not appearing in the hal browser.

[image]

Comment: Would you please share what's the response structure?

Comment: response is list of strings.

Comment: I have posted an answer (though not the complete one) for the sake of sharing snapshot and code. Would you please take a look and share the requested details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In continuation of my comments in the original post, I am writing this to share code and screesnshot. It may not be the complete answer.

Here is my Controller:

```
@RestController("generalController")
public class GeneralController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/urls")
    public List<String> getUrls() {
        return Arrays.asList("http://abc", "http:def", "http://ghe");
    }
}
```

Here is the response when the endpoint is hit from a normal browser:

```
[
"http://abc",
"http://def",
"http://ghe"
]
```

Here is the screenshot when the same endpoint is hot from the HAL browser:

[image]

I do not see any issues when I ran. Would you please post the full HAL browser snapshot that includes the original response for us to understand your issue better?

### Update After Clarifications from @ashish

Here is  why you do not see your API listed in HAL browser:

- HAL browser lists the links by scanning repositories (@Repository) and entities (@Entity) defined and forms its own links at the top level.
- It does not need `@RestController`. In fact, it totally ignores the rest controller and all its methods.
- You can always type the full URL of your usual REST APIs (exposed from @RestController) in HAL browser and view results.

Comment: thanks @fiveelements, my porblem is not response. I am getting response but `/getSomething` is not appearing in the hal brower entry point

Comment: The reason it is not appearing in the listing is you need to have the model and repository defined.

Comment: @ashish Please see the updated answer. You need to have a repository and corresponding entity defined for HAL browser to list links.

Comment: thanks a lot for that. I will see if I can add property and repository